# Alternative for BufferedOutputStream?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, bufferedoutputstream

This is my code snippet

```
@Override
    protected RecordWriter<String, String> getBaseRecordWriter(
            FileSystem fs, JobConf job, String name, Progressable arg3)
                    throws IOException {
        Path file2 = FileOutputFormat.getOutputPath(job);
        String path = file2.toUri().getPath()+File.separator+ name;
        FSDataOutputStream fileOut = new FSDataOutputStream( new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path, true),104857600)), null);
        return new LineRecordWriter<String, String>(fileOut, "\t");
    }
```

i am using Spark 1.6.1 and in my code i used `saveAsHadoopFile()` method for which i write a class OutputFormat derived from org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.MultipleTextOutputFormat and i overwrite the above method.

On cluster it writes corrupt records in output files.
i think it is because of `BufferedOutputStream` in

```
FSDataOutputStream fileOut = new FSDataOutputStream(
                 new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path, true),104857600)), null);
```

Can we have any alternative for `bufferedOutputStream`, since it writes as soon as the buffer gets full.

Note: updated the code. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: There is no `BufferedOutputStream` in your code, let alone any evidence for your belief that it is causing data corruption. Unclear what you're asking, and probable XY problem.

Comment: The only corruption a BufferedOutputStream can cause is a truncated file, but only if you fail to flush() or close() it.

Comment: I updated the code. I was trying different combinations hence got the wrong one.

Comment: The fact that `BufferedOutputStream` 'writes as soon as the buffer gets full' has no bearing on data corruption. You still have not explained your reasoning.

Comment: I got the issue .. on cluster each worker will try to write in same (shared)file as both workers on different machine means different JVM and hence synchronized file write wont work here. thats why the corrupt records.
Also i used NFS which is important factor.
I actually want to acquire file level write lock before writing to file.
any pointers on this will be helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue .. on cluster each worker will try to write in same (shared)file as both workers on different machine means different JVM and hence synchronized file write wont work here. thats why the corrupt records. Also i used NFS which is important factor.